# SCSS Loading error in angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using to AngularCLI to Angular2. I included sass preprocessor with SCSS syntax. But when i type ng serve or npm run build after eject i got something like this. I checked the directories and everything was fine, i read about SASS loader bug, but now i have the newest version where that bug is fixed. Does anyone have idea how i can fix it ?

Thank you in advance.

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-
loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?
{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.scss 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images/arrow_bullet-01.png' in 
'F:\Angular2Tests\bootstrapscss\src'
@ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?
{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?
{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.scss  
6:87042-87082
@ ./src/styles.scss
@ multi ./src/styles.scss

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-
loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?
{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-
regular.eot' in 'F:\Angular2Tests\bootstrapscss\src'
@ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?
{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?
{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.scss 
6:243131-243183 6:243206-243258
@ ./src/styles.scss
@ multi ./src/styles.scss

ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-
loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?
{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-
regular.woff' in 'F:\Angular2Tests\bootstrapscss\src'
@ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader?
{"ident":"postcss"}!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?
{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/styles.scss 
6:243310-243363
@ ./src/styles.scss
@ multi ./src/styles.scss
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with the `sass` library where it won't load files relative to it's importing file. For fonts, you might be required to import with an absolute path to your `src` directory.

The issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5213)

The `angular-cli` team decided to close it as it is an issue with the `sass` lib rather than the `cli`.